# HELP; CountIFs function?

Tags: ms-office, google, formatting

Cells F25:F406 contain dropdown lists with 15 different names.
Cells J25:J406 contain checkboxes.

I want one cell to count when 1 of those 15 people select their name from the dropdown list AND check the checkbox in the same row. For example, when Kelsi chooses her name in the dropbox on row 25 AND hits complete, I want that to count as "1". If Kelsi selects her name from multiple drop boxes but only checks 1 box, I want that to count as "1".

How do I make a formula that will count when a persons name AND a checked box of the same row occurs? I don't want it to count when just the persons name is mentioned or just when the box is checked but when BOTH happen at the same time.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Could you take a pass and edit this a bit? What program are you using? Office would likely be excel and google might mean sheets? iOS or MacOS or browser apps?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/50504366/4961700